# Can I rewire the cooker so I can use the gas oven without it being connected to the mains?

Tags: electrical

I'm planning on getting a freestanding gas cooker (LEISURE Cuisinemaster CS60GVK)  (all gas hobs/oven/grill etc) but it uses a normal plug for the ignition and led programmer. I know I can rewire the ignition to run off a 12v spark generator (that should be straight forward)  but reading through the manual it says I can't switch the oven on if the time isn't set on the led programmer, does this mean that if I don't have the programmer on, the oven won't work? I don't know why this would be but wanted to ask if any one knows of why this is and how or if I can bypass this as I don't need the programmer.

Comment: This is closer to an electronics question rather than Home Improvement.  For all we know, this unit might have some gas related safety features that are controlled by the electronics, and you wouldn't want to mess that up.

Answer (score 1):

In these ovens the programmer (often called the "timer") contains the circuitry which controls the oven temperature. I don't think you can use the oven without a functioning programmer.

You would need an "off-the-grid" range and oven: https://bensdiscountsupply.com/premier-bak100tp-20-battery-ignition-gas-range-biscuit-with-black-trim/